# Asynchronous vs synchronoous socket

Tags: .net, sockets, asynchronous

I have a situation that there will be 500 concurrent connection to server. In term of response time which method is faster? (asynchronous or synchronous) And what are the reasons behind?

I know asynchronous socket is like a list of connection, then it will ask each of the connection, do you have anything to send or receive. If the list is very long, then response time may take longer as well. Is this correct?

Comment: What OS are you on? What programming language? How do you implement synch/asynch sockets? Single- or multithreaded? If MT, how are threads handled? Without knowing that, it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Hi Anders. I'm using .Net to write socket server. I have done async socket with BeginReceive/EndReceive method. But on my testing, when server has around 500 active connections, the response time become slow. So i'm wondering will sync method more responsive.

Comment: Stuff like, "slows down at 500," provides important context. You should point this out in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you use synchronous sockets, then 500 connections will requires 500 threads. Bad idea. The scheduling cost of that many threads will dwarf the overhead of keeping an eye on 500 asynchronous sockets.

BTW, you don't cycle over each socket, asking it if it's ready to transmit. You use async APIs such as `select()`, or I/O completion ports.

Comment: If it won't have more than 500 connections. Will dedicated thread on each connection more responsive?

Comment: Async API's ought to be faster for as few as 10 concurrent connections. As a general rule, you should spawn as many threads as you have CPU cores, and use async I/O within each thread.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous sockets will work better. They use [IOCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) internally which is a very effective way to handle pending IO operations.

If you have a few sockets, use threads since it's ***easier***. Stick with asynchronous sockets otherwise.